# Where were the Vulcans during the final inspection?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In [VOY: Counterpoint](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Counterpoint_%28episode%29), Voyager's crew hide a number of telepathic refugees plus their own three crew members;  [**Jarot**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jarot), an otherwise unknown Betazoid and the two Vulcans, **Tuvok and Vorik** in a transporter buffer during the Devore's inspections.

During the last inspection however

> Inspector Kashyk told his men to check the buffers which turned out to be vegetables this time, while the refugees escaped through the wormhole.

---

Certainly Jarot is never mentioned again, but Tuvok and Vorik are clearly present in later episodes. **So how did they managed to hide during the final inspection?**

Comment: I've reworded the question slightly to remove the unsightly and unnecessary spoiler tags. It's not a secret that they're using the transport buffer, only a secret what the final twist is.

Comment: @Valorum You're right, it's not a secret after about 5 minutes into that episode. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a considerable number of transporters on board the Voyager. The inspectors only check the one in Cargo Bay One before realising that they've been duped **and leaving.**

> **KASHYK:** ***Go to Cargo Bay one.** You'll find the transporter patterns for more than a dozen telepaths. Rematerialise them.*
>
> **PRAX:** *Yes, sir.*
>
> ... [shortly afterwards]
>
> **KASHYK:** *To hell with protocol, Prax! Do you think either of us will benefit from having this failure on our records? As far as you're
> concerned, this incident never occurred. Make sure your teams share
> that understanding.*
>
> (Prax and the other Devore leave.)

Presumably the transporter in Cargo Bay Two (or any of the transporters in the Transporter room, the ship's shuttlecraft or the ship's emergency evac transporters on each deck) could have easily been fitted with the same modifications and used to hide the ship's small complement of telepathic officers from the Devore inspection team.

Comment: Or, for all we know, they held on to the outside of the hull in EVA suits.

Comment: @Xantec - I'd have assumed that the inspection team would be wise to those sorts of tricks, especially given that their ship has scanners and y'know, windows. The reason it worked before is that the transporter tech was new to them.

Comment: Indeed. The point, however, is that they could have hidden just about anywhere. Perhaps they just hung out in a Jefferies tube with a portable [thoron generator](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Thoron_generator).

Comment: @Xantec - My gut instinct is that if the trick worked once, the most likely action is that they'd try it again. If the ship gets impounded, they're dead either way.